# CSS: How to change facebook smileys?

Tags: css, facebook, stylesheet

Im making a stylesheet for facebook that i use in Stylish.
But i have stumbled upon something that i find pretty confusing.
Im trying to change the smileys in the chat to my own smileys image.

[Facebook smileys](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yM/r/WlL6q4xDPOA.png)
[My edited smileys](http://www.puffys.net/storage/facebook/darq/smileys.png)

Now, i tried to change .emote_img to my own background, but it only shows the first icon on all of the emoticons.

What do i need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

For details on writing your own chat client that you can use your own smileys on, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: I dont think you know what i ment, i was looking to only change emoticons in the web version of the facebook with CSS via Stylish. Im not going to build my own client.

Comment: Are you allowed to do that?  It seems to me that would be against Facebook policy to do so.